comparing results from 2 different authenticated accounts
In expanding our testing, we are looking to compare data between 2 different accounts.
One scenario is to verify that if a piece of equipment is present on one account but the second account is updated with that same piece of equipment, the item is removed from the first account.
Another scenario is that if an address is updated on a parent account, all related children accounts are also updated with the same address.
Since we test thru the API, we have to login to each account to verify.
I am curious how others are handling this if auth is a part of karate.config.

do you write results to a file to compare with the second account
do you have a process to log in multiple accounts within karate.config
do you have a separate auth process to login the subsequent accounts to compare to the initial
do you not test these scenarios due to limitations in the framework or teams current knowledge or don't encounter these scenarios

Looking for recommendations on implementation of such a test as there are numerous directions this could go and we would like to avoid headaches others may have faced.

Here's what I would do ideally, all this in a single Scenario, no fiddling with karate-config.js. I'll ignore the "parent-child" requirement for now.

Create fresh new account A - and assign equipment to it.
Create fresh new account B - and assign equipment to it.
Log into A
Log into B
Verify equipment X exists for A
Update B with X
Verify X has been removed from A

1 & 2 can use a re-usable feature, so can 3 and 4. I assume that logging in and "auth" is just a matter of storing the Authorization header and using it correctly. Nothing should prevent you from "logging in" to multiple accounts in the same Scenario.
Some teams choose to have A and B pre-created and re-used to save time. It can even be a couple of accounts that are assumed to exist "for ever". Or created when the test-suite starts - by using karate.callSingle(). The decision depends on how much time it takes to create accounts and how risky it is if you don't test the whole end-to-end flow.

Our accounts do not exist forever.  Additionally we test in multiple environments, so a pre-fixed account setup is not viable for us.

Since the login setup we have, uses callSingle() and sets our headers and auth tokens, I think our best solution is to duplicate code for the login, as a second accounts credentials and use those for our tests and comparisons since reuse is not going to work at this time

@mike I tried to be as clear as I can, finally the call is yours because only you know what kind of code you have written already and what kind of changes you are willing to make. for an account "comparison" use case, typically teams are able to juggle two or more credentials in the same Scenario. if you can't do that because of whatever reason, then all bets are off
